# Creating Regular Expression to search a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string that contains variables in the format {namespace:name} I am trying to create a regular expression for finding all of the variables in the string. I have the following so far, but it isn't working:

```
$str = " {user:fname} and the last name = {user:lname}";
var_dump(preg_match_all("/^\{(\w):(\w)\}/", $str, $matches));   
var_dump($matches);
```

But it isn't finding any of the tags. The variables can have any word for namespace and name, but letters only with no spaces. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

I tried the following also and received no results: `"/\{(\w):(\w)\}/"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the anchor `^` from the regex and allow variables with a length of more than one character.

```
/^\{(\w):(\w)\}/
```

becomes:

```
/\{(\w+):(\w+)\}/
```

Comment: Probably want to also add quantifiers to the `\w`s. Unless the tags are only 1 character.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That worked. Will give you the checkmark when I can.

Comment: @M42: You're welcome. I had overlooked the missing quantifier myself, and I had to justify my upvote :)